# How to script paste many values to many parts in HTML

Tags: html, google-apps-script

Example `entry` data look like

```
{
 acc : ["102 Cash on hand", "101 Cash at zummon Bank", "103 Cash at Wonder Bank", "300 Capital stock"], 
 amt : [800000.0, 100000.0, 100000.0, -1000000.0]
}
```

HTML script part. I want to paste `each entry data` to `each part in HTML` Help please!

```
function setEntry(entry) {
      var lenEntry = entry.acc.length
      for (var r=0; r < lenEntry; r++) {
        document.getElementById("entryAccount")[r].value = entry.acc[r]
        document.getElementById("entryAmount")[r].value = entry.amt[r]
      }
}
```

HTML parts

```
<div style="display:flex">
  <div>
    <label for="entryAccount">Account</label>
    <input id="entryAccount" list="Account_list">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="entryAmount">Amount</label>
    <input id="entryAmount" type="number">
  </div>
</div>
<div style="display:flex">
  <div>
    <label for="entryAccount">Account</label>
    <input id="entryAccount" list="Account_list">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="entryAmount">Amount</label>
    <input id="entryAmount" type="number">
  </div>
</div>
...
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I edited, I hope it's valid now

Comment: Still invalid. Strings should be quoted.

Comment: I'm sorry, I might understand incorrectly. But I've tried this `document.getElementById("entryAccount").value = entry.acc[0]` without `for (..)` and it works fine for a single value.

Comment: Or you mean just put " to be `"102 Cash on hand",...` It is string. I got them from `Logger.Log()` sorry I thought it didn't make any different

Comment: You can have only one element with 1 id. You can't have multiple  elements with the same id. `id` in html is unique.

Comment: Oh! that's why, I understand now. Thank you

Comment: Create a new div element with new id and append to document.

Comment: I found out that I can replace `get by id` to be `get by class name` and replace HTML structure `id` to be `class` This is an answer to me now. Should I close this question? By the way, your advice can also lead me to auto add elements. If my input boxes in HTML are less than entry data. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Consider adding it as a answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can have only one element with 1 id. You can't have multiple elements with the same id. id in html is unique - Thanks to [TheMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster)'s information

So a way around to get this work, would be using `getElementsByClassName` to accept many values

For HTML script part

```
document.getElementById("entryAccount")[r].value = entry.acc[r]
document.getElementById("entryAmount")[r].value = entry.amt[r]
```

edit to be

```
document.getElementsByClassName("entryAccount")[r].value = entry.acc[r]
document.getElementsByClassName("entryAmount")[r].value = entry.amt[r]
```

For HTML part

```
    <input id="entryAccount" list="Account_list">
    <input id="entryAmount" type="number">
    ...
```

add more class to `getElement`

```
    <input class="entryAccount" id="entryAccount" list="Account_list">
    <input class="entryAmount" id="entryAmount" type="number">
    ...
```

Or you can get rid of those `id="..."` and it still works the same way, if you don't mind `label for="..."`